# How can I download a list of files dynamically generated with javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, for-loop

I'm trying to create and loop through a list of links that point towards a dynamically generated XML file.

Here is the code I'm using . . . I've changed the url:

```
    function scanSystem() {
    // Starting value for scans
        var xMin = '0';
        var yMin = '0';
    // Temporary - The highest coordinates that will be scanned
        var coordMax = '19';

        for (var x = xMin; x <= coordMax; x++) {
            for (var y = yMin; y <= coordMax; y++) {
                var url = "http://www.xmlurl.com/members/scanners/list.php?cockpit&xml&x=" + x + "&y="+ y;
                var link = "<a href='" + url + "'>(" + x + "," + y + ")</a><br>";
                $("#links_container").append(link);
                document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
            }
        }
    }
```

The links generate and fill the div (which is more of a debug function at the moment) but only the last link is actually downloaded through the iframe.

Any ideas how to make it start the download of the other files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it is to dynamically create a hidden `iframe` for each link instead of opening new windows (which will be annoying). Each iframe will be loading each file individually.

Taking advantage that you are using jQuery already, here's sample code:

```
function scanSystem() {
  var x
    , y
    , coordMax = 19
    , url
    , linksContainer = $("#links_container")
    ;

  for (x = 0; x <= coordMax; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y <= coordMax; y++) {

      url = 'http://www.xmlurl.com/members/scanners/list.php?cockpit&xml&x=' + x + '&y=' + y;
      $('<a/>',{
          href : url
        })
        .text(x+','+y)
        .appendTo(linksContainer);

      $('<iframe/>',{
          src : url
        })
        .appendTo('body');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This did it. Applying a class that hid the iframes didn't, however. To fix that, I just remeoved that bit of code and then, instead of appending to the body, I appended them to a hidden div. Problem solved! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening the URLs in an iframe, just open them with `window.open`. Most browsers will immediately close the new window if it only downloads a file.

Comment: That did better. It downloaded 6 files as opposed to 1 but they're random. It's still not catching all of them. It seems like it's going to fast to actually process the links.

Comment: Well, you could delay them using `window.setTimeout`, like so: `window.setTimeout(function() { open the next one here }, 300);`